# how to insert text in top left corner or bottom left corner or in most right side of the pdf page for all exist pdf documents?

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfbox, itext7

I have so many exist pdf documents and all of them with different dimensions and rotation. I want to add small text like help note in top side or bottom side. I found so many examples in how to insert text but my problem I could not succeed to make it work in all different dimension with different rotation.
my code will be applicable only for few pdf documents. then if I need to make it working with all pages of all exist documents then I need to address all conditions with so long code.

here what I have tried with itext5:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {         
    String inputFilePath = "test.pdf"; // Existing file
       String outputFilePath = "output.pdf"; // New file

       OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFilePath));

       PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputFilePath);
       PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, fos);


       // loop on all the PDF pages
       // i is the pdfPageNumber
       for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
           Rectangle pageSize = pdfReader.getPageSize(i) ;
           int oldRotation = pdfReader.getPageRotation(i);
           System.out.println("oldRotation:"+oldRotation);

           System.out.println("Pdf page :"+pageSize+" PageSize.A2:"+PageSize.A2+" PageSize.A3:"+PageSize.A3+" PageSize.A4:"+PageSize.A4);
                                System.out.println("pageSize.getWidth():"+pageSize.getWidth());
                                System.out.println("pageSize.getHeight():"+pageSize.getHeight());
                                System.out.println("pageSize.getLeft():"+pageSize.getLeft());
                                System.out.println("pageSize.getRight():"+pageSize.getRight());
                                System.out.println("pageSize.getBottom():"+pageSize.getBottom());
                                System.out.println("pageSize.getTop():"+pageSize.getTop());

              if(oldRotation == 0 || oldRotation == 270 )
              {
                 PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfStamper.getOverContent(i);
                 Document document = pdfContentByte.getPdfDocument(); 
                 Font ffont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED, 5, Font.ITALIC);
                 Phrase header = new Phrase("this is a header", ffont);
                 Phrase footer = new Phrase("this is a footer", ffont);

                 float value1 = document.right() - document.left()) / 2 + document.leftMargin();
                 double value2 = document.top() + 10 ;

                    ColumnText.showTextAligned(pdfContentByte, Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                            header,
                            (value1,
                            value2, 0);
                    ColumnText.showTextAligned(pdfContentByte, Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                            footer,
                            (document.right() - document.left()) / 2 + document.leftMargin(),
                            document.bottom() - 10, 0);
                            pdfStamper.close(); //close pdfStamper
                }
                else if(oldRotation == 90 )
                  {
                          if(pageSize.toString().contains("1162.0")) // I gess A4
                         {
                            System.out.println("In 90 rotation pageSize.contains(1162)");
                            PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfStamper.getOverContent(i);
                             Document document = pdfContentByte.getPdfDocument(); 
                             Font ffont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED, 5, Font.ITALIC);
                             Phrase header = new Phrase("this is a header", ffont);
                             Phrase footer = new Phrase("this is a footer", ffont);

                             float value1 = (document.right() - document.left()) / 2 + document.leftMargin();
                             float value2 = document.top() ;
                                ColumnText.showTextAligned(pdfContentByte, Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                                        header,
                                        value1,
                                        value2, 0);

                                float value3 = (document.right() - document.left()) / 2 ;
                                float value4 = - 330 ;
                                ColumnText.showTextAligned(pdfContentByte, Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                                        footer,
                                        value3,
                                        value4, 0);
                                        pdfStamper.close(); //close pdfStamper
                            }// end if 
                            else if(pageSize.toString().contains("842.0x1191.0"))
                                {
                                    System.out.println("In 90 rotation pageSize.contains(842.0x1191.0)");
                                     PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfStamper.getOverContent(i);
                                     Document document = pdfContentByte.getPdfDocument(); 
                                     Font ffont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED, 5, Font.ITALIC);
                                     Phrase header = new Phrase("this is a header", ffont);
                                     Phrase footer = new Phrase("this is a footer", ffont);
                                        ColumnText.showTextAligned(pdfContentByte, Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                                                header,
                                                (document.right() - document.left()) / 2 + document.leftMargin(),
                                                document.top() + 10, 0);
                                        ColumnText.showTextAligned(pdfContentByte, Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                                                footer,
                                                (document.right() - document.left()) / 2 + document.leftMargin(),
                                                document.bottom() - 10, 0);
                                                pdfStamper.close(); //close pdfStamper
                                }

                    }



              }


       System.out.println("Modified PDF created in >> "+ outputFilePath);

}
```

Comment: *"here what I have tried with itext5"* - and how did it fail your expectations?

Comment: and did you also try something with pdfbox and with itext7? Or did you just use a few labels that have some relation to PDF?

Comment: "and how did it fail your expectations?", I have tried a lot with one code showing the text tn top of pdf for example, but unfortunately it will not work for other pdf due to different dimension ( size A3 , A4,other sizes)  and rotation. please try one time to have text in top and running in all pdf with different dimension and rotation and see if it works or not

Comment: and did you also try something with pdfbox and with itext7? Or did you just use a few labels that have some relation to PDF?. I have tried with PDFBox but with no succeed.

Comment: Your question is 3 different things (top left corner / bottom left corner / most right side) and this with 3 different software products, so that makes 9 questions. Re pdfbox, how about starting to show the code you tried for bottom left corner, then post a PDF where it didn't work? Because bottom left corner in PDFBox is coordinates (0,0).

Comment: In addition to needing more information about your requirements, you should understand there are different ways to define rotation. The PDF may be normal portrait orientation with no rotation. It might be normal in all other ways but then have a rotation. It might have no rotation angle specified but be a landscape page (wider than it is tall), with text oriented horizontally. Or it might be a landscape page with text written with a rotation. If you have each of those scenarios, they will have to be addressed individually, as they will require different code.